# Placing bids on eBay through sniping

Tags: ebay-api

Can anyone help me on how to place bid(s) on a given eBay item through sniping?

This is the requirement of one of my clients from Europe. I have implemented the eBay PlaceOffer API, but the client doesn't want to use that API as it needs to pass the review process by eBay Developer Support and the eBay Affiliate Program.

Answer (score 7):

The "base" eBay API does not have a feature in the API to "place-bids". The eBay API that can place bids is called "PlaceOffer" (as you have mentioned). PlaceOffer is basically an extension to the eBay API, but to use PlaceOffer, you must accept a separate license agreement for PlaceOffer ([PlaceOffer API License Agreement Addendum](http://developer.ebay.com/terms/PlaceOffer_API_License_Addendum_uv.pdf) PDF). There is a stipulation in the PlaceOffer API license Agreement, that you will not use the PlaceOffer API to do sniping (I.E.: can't have a feature to place a bid (or bids) on a buyer’s behalf based on time remaining or at a scheduled time).

The relevant portion of the [PlaceOffer API License Agreement Addendum](http://developer.ebay.com/terms/PlaceOffer_API_License_Addendum_uv.pdf) (PDF) is:

> > **NOW, THEREFORE**, for mutual and valuable consideration, the sufficiency and receipt of which are hereby acknowledged, the parties hereby agree as follows:
> >
> > 1. You are hereby granted limited access to eBay’s PlaceOffer functionality (“PlaceOffer”) as a Permitted Use under the Agreement.
> > 2. The parties agree to add the following at the end of Section 16 to the Agreement:
> >
> > > **“You hereby acknowledge and agree that:**
> > >
> > > > (i) You will not make any public statement regarding the terms of this Amendment
> > > >         __ without eBay’s prior written approval, which may be withheld in eBay’s sole
> > > >         discretion;
> > > >
> > > > (ii) You will **not provide or operate an automated sniping tool** (defined as any
> > > >         application or feature of an application that **places a bid (or bids) on a buyer’s
> > > >         behalf based on time remaining or at a scheduled time**); and
> > > >
> > > > (iii) You will use PlaceOffer in accordance with the following guidelines:
> > > >
> > > > > (a) Your Application using PlaceOffer is subject to certification as
> > > > >           set forth in the Agreement;
> > > > >
> > > > > (b) automated use of PlaceOffer **may not be specifically scheduled
> > > > >           for a later time**, and
> > > > >
> > > > > (c) use of PlaceOffer must be made in accordance with the eBay
> > > > >           User Agreement and bidding policies.**”**

This is also described in the [PlaceOffer Policies and Guidelines](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/ebay/PlaceOffer.html#PoliciesGuidelines):

> > **The following PlaceOffer policies are required for applications that use this call in the production environment:**
> >
> > ■ Use of **PlaceOffer** must be in accordance with the [API License Agreement](http://developer.ebay.com/join/licenses/Default.aspx) and the [eBay User Agreement](http://pages.ebay.com/help/policies/user-agreement.html). If you are an eBay affiliate, you must agree to all terms and conditions specific to the eBay programs you join.
> >     ■ **The automatic and/or scheduled use of PlaceOffer is prohibited.** An example is **sniping, which is prohibited**. For each **PlaceOffer** call made by your application, **the user first must take an explicit action**. That is, the application needs to get confirmation from the user before making each PlaceOffer call.
> >     ■ **The application shall not in any way, shape, or form collect the eBay username and password values of buyers or sellers** that are involved in order line items. Users must enable bidding and buying through eBay's Authentication & Authorization mechanisms.
> >     ...
> >     ...
> >     ■ To use **PlaceOffer** in the production environment, you must apply for, and be granted, approval by the eBay Partner Network. Additionally, your application must be functional in the sandbox environment.
> >
> > Please also note the following policies regarding use of **PlaceOffer** in the production environment:
> >
> > ■ After you apply for approval by the eBay Partner Network, and if it is granted, then you must pass an application review by eBay Developer Support.
> >     ■ The review process can take 10 business days or longer. In addition, before **PlaceOffer** access is granted in production, you must sign and return the [eBay PlaceOffer API License Agreement Addendum](http://developer.ebay.com/terms/PlaceOffer_API_License_Addendum_uv.pdf) (PDF).

As an alternative to using the eBay API, including the PlaceOffer API (which does not allow sniping anyway), you could look at [JBidWatcher: Free eBay sniping, bidding & monitoring](http://www.jbidwatcher.com/) and [JBidWatcher: Economics vs. the eBay API](http://www.jbidwatcher.com/why_not_api) as a starting place. Also, see [JBidWatcher on GitHub](https://github.com/cyberfox/jbidwatcher)

---

You could also look at the (eBay Sniping) API at [Gixen eBay Sniper](http://www.gixen.com/index.php).

Comment: For those of you looking for the eBay PlaceOffer API License Agreement, here is a working link for me: http://go.developer.ebay.com/terms/PlaceOffer_API_License_Addendum_uv.pdf

Comment: So how do those ebay sniping sites actually do the sniping if eBay does not permit it?

Comment: @Tony - There are only two ways (as far as I know) to do automated sniping. 1) Ignore the eBay rules and use the eBay "PlaceOffer API" to do the sniping. 2) The way most do it: the user trusts the sniping service and provides their "eBay Username" and "eBay Password" to the sniping service, and the sniping service automates the process of logging in and placing the bid through the normal web interface on eBay.com as though a person has logged in and placed a bid.